# Principles of Mathematical Induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Using the principles of mathematical induction prove:

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$$
for $n > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb N$

My attempt:

Let the statement $P(n)$ be:
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$$

STEP 1: We first show that $P(1)$ is true.

Left Hand Side =  $$\frac{1}{2}$$

Right Hand Side = $$\frac{2^1-1}{2^1} = 1/2$$

Both sides of the statement are equal hence $P(1)$ is true.

STEP 2: We now assume that $P(k)$ is true.

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}+2^{k+1}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$$

$$=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$$

$$=2^{k+1}-1 + k+1 = 2^{k+1}-1$$

Hence, 
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Please check line 1 and 2 of step 2.

Comment: the induction step is to show how $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$.  Use the supposed truth of $P(n)$ by adding to it the $n+1$ th term and show that you can manipulate it into $P(n+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base case looks fine, but I am very confused about your induction step.  First off, I don't understand how one line relates to the next (are these implications?  or, as you have written, equalities?).  Second, I don't follow the argument at all.  If I were writing it up, I would likely do the following:

For induction, suppose that
$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{2^k-1}{2^k}. \tag{IH}$$
This statement, labeled (IH) is the *induction hypothesis*. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}
&= \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{2^k}}_{\text{right-hand side of (IH)}} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \\
&= \frac{2^{k}-1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} && (\text{by the induction hypothesis}) \\
&= \frac{2^{k}-1}{2^k}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{2}{2}} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} && (\text{to get a common denominator}) \\
&= \frac{2^{k+1} - 2}{2^{k+1}} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \\
&= \frac{2^{k+1} - 1}{2^{k+1}}.
\end{align}
Therefore if (IH) holds, then
$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{2^{k+1} - 1}{2^{k+1}}, $$
which completes the induction proof.$\tag*{$\square$}$

---

Alternatively, if you wish to start with an identity and manipulate that, you could assume (IH), then work as follows:

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{2^k-1}{2^{k+1}} \\
&\qquad\implies \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{2^k} \color{red}{+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}} = \frac{2^k-1}{2^{k+1}} \color{red}{+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}} = \frac{2^{k+1} - 1}{2^k},
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from the same argument as above.  In any event, this also gives the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow your reasoning.

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}\text{(index off by } 1)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}+2^{k+1}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}\text{(Not true)}$$

$$=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}} \text{(True, but where does it comes from)}$$

$$=2^{k+1}-1 + k+1 = 2^{k+1}-1 \text{(Not true)}$$

Correction:

We assume $P(k)$ is true, that is

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ \ldots+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{2^{k}-1}{2^{k}}$$

What we want to show is $P(k+1)$,

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ \ldots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$$

Start from LHS of $P(k+1)$, try to reach RHS of $P(k+1)$.

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ \ldots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k}-1}{2^{k}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$$

Try to simplify the expression to get RHS of $P(k+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Step 2: Assume that the formula is correck for $n=k$ and show that the formula will work for $n=k+1$. Thus, we assume that $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2\cdot 2^k-2+1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the part $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$ is incorrect, because $LHS=P(k)$ but $RHS=P(k+1)$.

Here's how you can continue:

Assume that $P(k)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{2^{k}-1}{2^{k}}$ (not $2^{k+1}$)

We will have $P(k+1)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^k+1}=\frac{2^{k}-1}{2^{k}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-2}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$

The proof can be easily finished from there.